# Download Last 24 hour files from s3 using Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I have an s3 bucket with different filenames. I need to download specific files (filenames that starts with impression) that are created or modified in last 24 hours from s3 bucket to local folder using powershell?

```
$items = Get-S3Object -BucketName $sourceBucket -ProfileName $profile -Region 'us-east-1' | Sort-Object LastModified -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | select Key Write-Host "$($items.Length) objects to copy" $index = 1 $items | % { Write-Host "$index/$($items.Length): $($_.Key)" $fileName = $Folder + ".\$($_.Key.Replace('/','\'))" Write-Host "$fileName" Read-S3Object -BucketName $sourceBucket -Key $_.Key -File $fileName -ProfileName $profile -Region 'us-east-1' > $null $index += 1 }
```

Comment: Nice, what have you tried?

Comment: I am able to download the file that is last modified but want to limit to check for file name that contains "impression" and is modified within 24 hours only. Below is my logic

Comment: $items = Get-S3Object -BucketName $sourceBucket -ProfileName $profile -Region 'us-east-1' | Sort-Object LastModified -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | select Key
Write-Host "$($items.Length) objects to copy"
$index = 1
$items | % {
    Write-Host "$index/$($items.Length): $($_.Key)"
    $fileName = $Folder + ".\$($_.Key.Replace('/','\'))"
    Write-Host "$fileName"
    Read-S3Object -BucketName $sourceBucket -Key $_.Key -File $fileName -ProfileName $profile -Region 'us-east-1' > $null
    $index += 1
}

Comment: Please use the [edit] button and add your code snippet _inside_ the Q.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to turn on access log, and since the access log will contain timestamp, you can get all access logs in the past 24 hours, de-duplicate repeated S3 objects, then download them all.

You can enable S3 access log in the bucket settings, the logs will be stored in another bucket.

If you end up writing a script for this, just bear in mind downloading the S3 objects will essentially create new access logs, making the operation irreversible.

If you want something fancy perhaps you can even query the logs and perhaps deduplicate using AWS Athena.

Comment: I don't have full access to the s3 bucket. All I have is the access key and secret access key to download files. I need to download them via scirpt only

Comment: then I believe based on the limitation this is not possible. there is meta data and last access time is not available in the meta data.

Comment: what about the logic that I uploaded? Can that be modified to accommodate my needs?